# Display a heading for a stash:get_list if there are more than X entries

Tags: stash

I have a stash set list that's getting all the entries from a channel as follows;

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="items-{segment_2}" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="3"}
    {exp:tag:related_entries
        channel="items"
        orderby="title"
        sort="asc"
    }
        {stash:item_id}{entry_id}{/stash:item_id}
        {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
        {stash:item_count}{count}{/stash:item_count}
    {/exp:tag:related_entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

I'm then using a get list as follows, first to get the first 3 items and then again to get all the rest in the "more_items" div;

```
<h1>Items <a href="">View more</a></h1>

<div class="items">
{exp:stash:get_list name="items-{segment_2}" limit="3"}
{item_title}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
</div>

<div class="more_items">
{exp:stash:get_list name="items-{segment_2}" offset="3"}
{item_title}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
</div>
```

You'll notice I have a h1 that contains a link to View more. This has some JS to handle the reveal of the "more_items" div. However, i'd like to hide the View more link if there are only 3 or less items.

I have tried moving the heading inside the first list but because it is limited by 3 it can't figure out if there are more than 3 to show the link.

I would be grateful if anyone has any advice. :)

Comment: Use a conditional with list_count https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Alist_count%7D

Comment: Jeremy's answer above was spot on.

Comment: @JeremyDaalder, please, post your answer properly. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if it is, please mark Jeremy's answer as 'the answer'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a standard EE conditional with (https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Alist_count%7D) the stash function list_count to do this. list_count can be used to return the total count, or the count of a filtered list. Very handy!

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use the `{count}` or `{absolute_results}` function ?

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="items-{segment_2}" parse_conditionals="yes"}
//^ parse_conditionals may be required
{if absolute_results >= 3}<h1>Items <a href="">View more</a></h1>{/if}
//^ unsure of wrapping results, may need {} ??
{/exp:stash:get_list}

<div class="items">
{exp:stash:get_list name="items-{segment_2}" limit="3"}
{item_title}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
</div>

<div class="more_items">
{exp:stash:get_list name="items-{segment_2}" offset="3"}
{item_title}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
</div>
```

Obviously if you "view more" conditional sat directly beneath the {get_list limit="3"} you could put the conditional inside and save an additional query.